# PHOTOSHOP/JSX: How to efficiently check if tool was used

Tags: javascript, macos, photoshop

I am trying to create a small script which will read how many steps were made while editing specific image. While also checking what tools were used. And then export all the results into various categories in .csv.

I have the Output part. 
I have the history states.

But how would you check if specific tool e.g.: Liquify, Clone Stamp, Free Transform etc. was used?

I have the below script. Which quickly checks if I used the tool, but if it wasn't used, it throws an error:

```
No such Element. Line: 13
->      var LiquifyUsed = app.activeDocument.historyStates.getByName('Liquify');
```

```js
var LiquifyUsed = app.activeDocument.historyStates.getByName('Liquify');

//Check if Liquify was used

if (LiquifyUsed = true) {
 alert ("Liquify was used")
} else {
 alert ("It was not used")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply catch the exception:

```
var liquifyUsed = false;
try {
    app.activeDocument.historyStates.getByName('Liquify');
    liquifyUsed = true;
} catch(e) {
    // assume the error is always "No such element" --
    // you could be more fastidious and check instead.
}
alert('Liquify used: ' + liquifyUsed);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was super quick! Works flawlessly! I have tried using try/catch but in a little different way .... I still need to practice more! I will accept your answer as soon as it allows me too :)